# Filtrar datos en Laravel con CheckBox

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy intentando realizar un filtro de datos con checkbox pero no he podido realizarlo.

Este es el formulario

```html
    <form method="GET" action="/futbol/futbolistas">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="checkbox" name="posicion" value="delantero"> Delanteros</br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="posicion" value="portero"> Porteros</br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="posicion" value="defensas"> Defensas</br>
        <input type="submit" >
    </form>
```

Lo que quiero es que se visualicen solamente los campos que pertenezcan al checkbox

Tengo un Buscador que ya funciona
Solo no se como realizar el filtrado de datos por el checkbox

Este es mi modelo

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class Futbol extends Model
{
    protected $connection='mysql';
    protected $table="cards";

    public function scopeSearch($query, $nombre){

        return $query->where('nombre','LIKE',"%$nombre%");
    }


}
```

Aquí esta mi controlador.

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Futbol;

class FutbolController extends Controller
{
    public function inicio(){
        return view('screens.inicio');
    }

    public function futbolistas(Request $request){


    $cards=Futbol::search($request->nombre)->get();


return view('screens.futbolistas', compact('cards'));

}

}
```

Lo que quiero es que se visualicen solo los datos de los valores del checkbox
Debe de funcionar de tal forma que al escoger "Delanteros" solo se muestren los "Delanteros"
Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Existen 2 problemas.

1. El nombre del input es `posicion` (si miras el html está como `name="posicion"`.
2. Según la lógica el input, se pueden obtener una o más posiciones a la vez, por lo tanto, el query de la búsqueda está incorrecto porque solo está buscando un valor único.

Dicho lo anterior, se puede cambiar el método se búsqueda para que pueda filtrar por una o varias posiciones:

```php
public function scopeSearch($query, $posiciones){

    return $query->whereIn('nombre', $posiciones);
}
```

Ahora bien, se atrapan las posiciones seleccionadas:

```php
public function futbolistas(Request $request){

    $posiciones = $request->input('posicion', []);
    $cards = Futbol::search($posiciones)->get();
    return view('screens.futbolistas', compact('cards'));

}
```