# ¿Como puedo concatenar dos funciones en una variable?

Tags: php, laravel

Necesito poder darle dos valores a la variable, son como condiciones.

```
$cards = Str::finish(Futbol::search($request->nombre), Futbol::Check($request->posicion))->get();
```

Cuando lo ejecuto en laravel me manda el siguiente error:

[image: Error]

¿Me podrían ayudar, por favor?

Comment: ¿Dos valores a la variable? creo que no entendí esa parte... ¿un array?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Filtrar datos en Laravel con CheckBox](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/526605/filtrar-datos-en-laravel-con-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada debes estar seguro que los dos métodos devuelvan un string (cadena de caracteres).

y esto lo logras de la siguiente forma:

```php
$str1 = Futbol::search($request->nombre);
$str2 = Futbol::Check($request->posicion);

if(is_string($str1) && is_string($str2)){
    $cards = Str::finish(
        $str1,
        $str2
    )->get();
}else{
    $cards = 'Los datos no son cadenas de texto';
}
```

si no son string, te van salir el mensaje de error, que son parte de una validación, puede poner datos no encontrados o tendrías que aprovechar a evaluar el objeto o error que te devuelve.